# Not able to push/pull to google repository

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, atlassian-sourcetree, google-cloud-repository

My colleague cloned my repository on google cloud and I was able to push/pull properly and now he is gone. On google I accidentally created new credentials and I lost my access to repository which I think I need to use new credentials if I am right.
[image]

[image]

At the moment I am following this:
 [image]

By clicking on Generate and store your git credentials I have this:
[image]

Would you please help me what should I do? I am confused as my repository is cloned earlier maybe I just need to change the credentials only.
Many thanks

Comment: Did you try cloning using the option `Google Cloud SDK`? You can check [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart#clone_a_repository) for further details.

Also, could you provide more details? I see you are showing the option for Windows users, but maybe you could verify that you are using Windows. Also, the error you are getting when cannot push/pull would be helpful.

In any case, you could verify that your file `.gitcookies` is not empty and has the generated key?

Comment: @PabloAlmécijaRodríguez Thanks for your response. I am windows user. Error for push/pull is shown in the second picture. I am not using Google Cloud SDK as installation has some issues so previous time it was done manually.

Comment: Did you run the commands you have in the last picture, in the yellow box, in the Windows cmd? Also, as I said before, did you check your `.gitcookies` file?